# Advising javax.persistence.EntityManager with AspectJ not working

Tags: spring, aspectj, entitymanager

I am trying to advise `javax.persistence.EntityManager` with AspectJ and Spring. It just does not work: no error and no ***"caught"*** on the console...

**Here is my aspect:**

```
package trc.suivi.aspects;

public aspect EventManagerAspect {

    public EventManagerAspect() {}

    pointcut catchIt() : (execution(* javax.persistence.EntityManager.persist(..)));

    after() returning: catchIt() {
        System.out.println("caught");
    }

}
```

**Here is how I configured my aspect in Spring:**

```
<bean class="trc.suivi.aspects.EventManagerAspect" factory-method="aspectOf"/>
```

Comment: Using `call` instead of `execution` works. Why that is: I don't know... If someone more seasoned in AspectJ can jump in a provide an explanation that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between call and execution is:

with `call` you are advising your code, with `execution` you are advising the target code (in this context, advising roughly means: changing the byte code of). And since the target code is in a jar your compiler doesn't have access to, this won't work.

Using `call` will do in most cases, but if you absolutely need to use `execution`, you have to either re-compile the external libraries with aspectj or use load time weaving.

Comment: One question though: is `javax.persistence.EntityManager` considered **my code**?

Comment: No, it's in an external jar. Your code is the code you are compiling. You are not compiling Entitymanager, you are linking against it. That's a difference.